# Are phone calls via WiFi VOIP encrypted by A5/1, A5/2, and A5/3?

Tags: encryption, wifi, gsm, voip

I have enabled a function in my mobile phone, that uses my home Wi-Fi network to make calls when the cellular signal does not exist. As far as I know, the cellphone provider charges me as though I make calls through its cellular network.

When I make calls using my mobile phone and the Wi-Fi network (not the cellular network), do I have A5/1, A5/2, A5/3 encryption/decryption or only Wi-Fi encryption/decryption or none of them?

I suppose that If I have both Ax/y encryption/decryption and Wi-Fi encryption/decryption I should have increased delays...but I really do not know...

Comment: Have you looked this up? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+wifi+calling+work The question back to you is "encrypted with Ax/y *at what point?*"